# How to solve special Diophantine equation systems (which one can solve by hand) with the computer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, computability-theory, diophantine-equations, computer-algebra

I have a quadratic Diophantine equation system which is possibly not homogeneous and has some mixed and some linear terms.

But I know that there are only finitely many solutions over the integers.

One can find all solutions by hand, but I would like to find all solutions with the computer.

> Question: Is this possible? Is there a program available which is capable of doing this?

If not, why can one solve it by hand then?

**Example:**

[(I)] $2x_1^2+4x_1x_{10} +2x_1x_{11} + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_1x_3 + 2x_{10}^2 +4x_{10}x_2 + 4x_{10}x_3 + 2x_{12}x_3 + 2x_{13}x_2 + 2x_2^2 + 2x_2x_3 +2x_3^2=0$

[(II)] $x_1x_{12}+x_1x_{13}+2x_1x_5 + x_1x_7 + x_1x_9 + x_{10}x_{11} + x_{10}x_{12} + x_{10}x_{13} + 2x_{10}x_5 +2x_{10}x_7 + 2x_{10}x_9 + x_{11}x_2 + x_{11}x_3 + x_{11}x_5 + x_{12}x_2 + x_{12}x_7 + x_{13}x_3 + x_{13}x_9 + x_2x_5 + x_2x_7 + 2x_2x_9 + x_3x_5 + 2x_3x_7 +x_3x_9=0$

[(III)] $x_1x_{12}+x_1x_{13}+2x_1x_4+x_1x_6+x_1x_8+x_{10}x_{11}+x_{10}x_{12}+x_{10}x_{13} + 2x_{10}x_4 + 2x_{10}x_6 + 2x_{10}x_8 + x_{11}x_2 + x_{11}x_3 + x_{11}x_4 + x_{12}x_2 + x_{12}x_8 + x_{13}x_3 + x_{13}x_6 + x_2x_4 + 2x_2x_6 + x_2x_8 + x_3x_4 + x_3x_6 + 2x_3x_8=0$

[(IV)] $x_1x_{12} + x_1x_{13} + 2x_1x_5 + x_1x_7 + x_1x_9 + x_{10}x_{11} + x_{10}x_{12} + x_{10}x_{13} + 2x_{10}x_5 + 2x_{10}x_7 + 2x_{10}x_9 + x_{11}x_2 + x_{11}x_3 + x_{11}x_5 + x_{12}x_2 + x_{12}x_7 + x_{13}x_3 + x_{13}x_9 + x_2x_5 + x_2x_7 + 2x_2x_9 + x_3x_5 + 2x_3x_7 + x_3x_9=0$

[(V)] $x_1x_{12} + x_1x_{13} + 2x_1x_4 + x_1x_6 + x_1x_8 + x_{10}x_{11} + x_{10}x_{12} + x_{10}x_{13} + 2x_{10}x_4 + 2x_{10}x_6 + 2x_{10}x_8 + x_{11}x_2 + x_{11}x_3 + x_{11}x_4 + x_{12}x_2 + x_{12}x_8 + x_{13} x_3 + x_{13}x_6 + x_2x_4 + 2x_2x_6 + x_2x_8 + x_3x_4 + x_3x_6 +2x_3x_8=0$

[(VI)] $2x_{11}x_7 + 2x_{11}x_9 + 2x_{12}x_5 + 2x_{12}x_9 + 2x_{13}x_5 + 2x_{13}x_7 + 2x_5^2 + 2x_5x_7 + 2x_5x_9 + 2x_7^2 + 2x_7x_9 + 2x_9^2=0$

[(VII)] $2x_{11}x_6 + 2x_{11}x_8 + 2x_{12}x_4 + 2x_{12}x_6 + 2x_{13}x_4 + 2x_{13}x_8 + 2x_4^2 + 2x_4x_6 + 2x_4x_8 + 2x_6^2 + 2x_6x_8 + 2x_8^2=0$

[(VIII)] $x_{11}^2 + x_{11}x_6 + x_{11}x_7 + x_{11}x_8 + x_{11}x_9 + x_{12}^2 + x_{12}x_4 + x_{12}x_5 + x_{12}x_6 + x_{12}x_9 + x_{13}^2 + x_{13}x_4 + x_{13}x_5 + x_{13}x_7 + x_{13}x_8 + 2x_4x_5 + x_4x_7 + x_4x_9 + x_5x_6 + x_5x_8 + x_6x_7 + 2x_6x_9 + 2x_7x_8 + x_8x_9=0$

[(IX)] An equation which is equivalent to equation [(VIII)]

[(X)] $2x_{10}^2+2x_{10}x_{11}+2x_{10}x_{12}+2x_{10}x_{13}=0$

[(XI)] $x_{11}^2+x_{12}^2+x_{13}^2=1$

[(XII)] $x_{11}x_{12}+x_{12}x_{13}+x_{13}x_{11}=0$

[(XIII)] $x_{11}x_{12}+x_{11}x_{13}+x_{12}x_{13}=0$

We see from the last 3 equations that there are only 6 possibilities for $x_{11}, x_{12}$ and $x_{13}$. Plugging these in, we get all possibilities for equation [(X)]...and finally we get not so difficult quadratic Diophantine equations in only 9 variables (as subsubcases of the previous cases)...which then are easy / easier to solve, since they are often nice (e.g. of the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + x + y -z =0$).

> Is there an intelligent program that would choose equations [(11)] - [(13)] first and then start building a tree with limbs and so on?

Remark1: All my equation systems have this "tree with limbs"-style.

Remark2: With "possibly non-homogeneous" I mean two things:

1. At the beginning we have only one equation $=1$, rest $=0$.
2. At the beginning we have no linear terms, but if we plug in sth. like $x_{11}=1$ into the other equations, the remaining system may become inhomogeneous and it may have some terms like $... +2\cdot x_j= ...$.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A computer might prefer $x_1, \ldots, x_{13}$ to $a, \ldots m$. But if you want commentary from humans, the equations would be easier to read with the different variables named by different letters.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for the comment. I did improve the layout and also simplify a few equations. Notice that the system above is only an example I chose (since it might be relatively close to a prototype).

Comment: @MattF. Thanks for the comment. I will do it, but for me it is 3:32 in the morning, so I will not do it right now. To all: Have a good night   :-)

Comment: The `FindInstance[]` function in Wolfram Mathematica can do this.

Comment: There is no general algorithm for solving systems of quadratic Diophantine equations. This follows from Matijasevich's theorem combined with the simple observation that every system of Diophantine equations can be reduced to a quadratic system with the help of additional variables. So if you can solve a quadratic system by hand, you are lucky and smart. Same for the computer: sometimes computers are lucky and smart as well!

Comment: @Somos Thank you for the comment. Can FindInstance find all solutions (when I know that there are only finitely many)?

Comment: @GHfromMO Thank you for your comment. I know the theorem of Matijasevich et al., but I was hoping for an existing CAS which would pick out a subset of all equations where the computer can find all solutions and then start producting the tree intelligently.

Comment: The inner workings of Mathematica functions are not documented. At most, if `FindInstance` returns results, then they satisfy the conditions, but, in general, it is unknown if they are **all** of  the solutions.